# Does natural outdoors wind affect the readings of an ultrasonic sensor significantly?

Tags: sensors, ultrasonics

I am thinking of using an ultrasonic sensor outdoors, and am wondering if the presence of wind (say up to 20km/h) would significantly impact the accuracy of the readings, or would this not be a large concern?

Thanks.

Comment: why would "natural" and "outdoors" make a difference? ... it is air movement ... run some tests using a hair dryer

Comment: Ah that's true, I added outdoor to give an idea of the wind speeds I'm considering. Your idea with using a hair dryer is pretty good, I'll give that a shot, thanks!

Comment: google `ultrasonic anemometer`

Comment: you did not say what you are measuring with the ultrasonic sensor, or how it is configured ... if it is a distance sensor module with the emitter and detector beside each other, then my gut feeling tells me that wind from directly in front, or directly in back would not make much difference ... any side to side air movement would increase the length of the sound travel .... i could easily be very wrong on this

Comment: As speed of sound is around 1235 km/h at 25°C, it' won't do so much difference for 20km/h (in the same direction as measurement) - it's under 2%

Comment: @KIIV i think that wind in same direction would not affect it much, because the sound propagation would speed up in one direction and slow down in the other direction

Comment: @jsotola true, completely forgot about that